# Are there any efficient python libraries for Dynamic Topic Models, preferably extending Gensim?

Tags: python, lda, text-analysis, topic-modeling, gensim

I'm trying to model twitter stream data with topic models. Gensim, being an easy to use solution, is impressive in it's simplicity. It has a truly online implementation for LSI, but not for LDA. For a changing content stream like twitter, Dynamic Topic Models are ideal. Is there any way, or even a hack - an implementation or even a strategy, using which I can utilize Gensim for this purpose?

Are there any other python implementations which derive (preferably) from Gensim or independent? I am preferring python, since I want to get started asap, but if there is an optimum solution with some work, please mention it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Gensim (http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/dtmmodel.html) has a python wrapper for the orig. C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

The DTM wrapper in Gensim is working, but none of the documentation is particularly complete at this time. On the Gensim side, the most useful thing to look at is [the DTM example](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/0.12.4/docs/notebooks/dtm_example.ipynb) buried in `docs/notebooks`. This shows you what all of the input variables need to look like. A couple of things to note:

- the DTM model has been moved into `gensim.models.wrappers.dtmmodel`
- `initialize_lda=True` must be set because of [a bug in the DTM code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gensim/dtm/gensim/A_qiR2NN6PE/n55zAi4PAgAJ) (this will be the default in future -- [PR #676](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/pull/676))

You'll also need a working compiled version of DTM itself (you provide the path to that executable). You can try using [the appropriate executable from a github repo](https://github.com/magsilva/dtm/tree/master/bin), but if that doesn't work you'll probably need to compile the [original code](https://github.com/blei-lab/dtm) by running the included `makefile`.

Answer (score 2):

Having talked with David Blei and John Lafferty about exactly this, the answer right now is no, there aren't.

Sean Gerrish's [DTM implementation](http://code.google.com/p/princeton-statistical-learning/downloads/detail?name=dtm_release-0.8.tgz) works with a documented memory leak, but works on manageable collections.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This implementation is in C++, directly referenced from Blei's page, which is by far the only endorsed/mature implementation I could come across. I am still looking an implementation in Python.